# Pause CS-Script

Tags: c#, scripting

Is there an equivalent to Lua's lua_yield when using CS-Script, to pause a script, and continue later, once you have the required data? An example could be a script, that calls a yes or no function, and the answer has to be received over network from a client first.

Comment: do you need C# solution or CS Script?

Comment: I want to call a C# function from a script to get some information. Since this information comes from a connected client, I first have to wait now, so the script has to be paused. Once I have the information, I want to jump back in where I left of, so the script can continue with the answer.

Comment: You can use `yield` to accomplish something like this, but as [Eric Said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10259997), Async is what you really want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are adding that feature to C# 5, which is in beta right now.

You can read about it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/async

Comment: Yes, I had the same 'notion' - but how would that work if you call into C# (from a CLR based scripting language - that doesn't implement async/await - though it's not clear if that's what @Mars really wants). And why wait for C#5 :), it is permitted for production. Anyway, I really enjoy your compiler related answers.